# How Do I Get Input Using PlainText?

Tags: java, android

`firstNumber` and `secondNumber` are of type EditText. I am trying to get the values from `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` and convert them to type `float`, but when I am doing that I am getting an Exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException`, I am unable to figure the solution to the problem. Kindly, please help.

Here's the code

```
firstNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstNumber);
secondNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.secondNumber);
result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
s1 = firstNumber.getText().toString();
s2 = secondNumber.getText().toString();
num1 = Float.parseFloat(s1);
num2 = Float.parseFloat(s2);
```

Logcat I am getting is -

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.calcmpttos, PID: 17846
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calcmpttos/com.example.calcmpttos.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Enter First Number"
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Enter First Number"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at com.example.calcmpttos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-07-07 20:29:53.693 17846-17846/com.example.calcmpttos I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 17846 SIG: 9
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Enter First Number"` means that `"Enter First Number"` is not a valid numeric string, such as `"115"`, `"0"`, `"2019"`, ... Therefore, it can't be parsed as a numeric type.

Comment: As already told by @Fantômas You have to restrict your editText to have numerical strings only, have a look at my answer. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Enter First Number"
```

Make sure you don't use the function with anything but a number.
So if you are using edit text make sure there are only numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can set digits to bypass the error:

```
firstNumber.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
secondNumber.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789"));
```

So only numbers can be typed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restrict your editText to have numerical values only. Add this to the editTexts where you wish to add numerical values

```
android:inputType="number"
```

or

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal
```

You can also do this by using

```
firstNumber.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant just throw a string that does not contain a parsable Float to parseFloat and expect it to parse it, That's why you got NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Float.valueOf()`

```
float num1 = Float.valueOf(firstNumber.getText().toString());
float num2 = Float.valueOf(secondNumber.getText().toString());
```

and add

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal
```

to your `EditText's`.